# Spark divide each dataframe column by a scalar using map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How would I divide each column in spark dataframe which has columns c1, c2, c3 , c4.
With its corresponding scalar. Scalar values are stored in a map or dataframe like:

```
c1->2
c2->4
c3->1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With map:

```
val map = Map("c1" -> 2, "c2" -> 4, "c3" -> 1)
```

and `DataFrame`:

```
val df = Seq((1, 1, 1, 1)).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")
```

it is just one line:

```
df.select(df.columns.map(c => (col(c) / map.getOrElse(c, 1)).alias(c)): _*).show

// +---+----+---+---+
// | c1|  c2| c3| c4|
// +---+----+---+---+
// |0.5|0.25|1.0|1.0|
// +---+----+---+---+
```